# Change letter case in strings with regular expressions

Tags: regex, pcre

For example, if I have strings in my code

```
AString
BString
CString
DString
EString
```

How do I best make them all be

```
aString
bString
cString
dString
eString
```

with regular expressions? My IDE doesn't have scripting capabilities so I can't do it in an alphabetic loop and there are about a hundred of files that need the edits. I can run a regular expression on multiple files though.

Comment: What's your ide? Do you have sed or awk or something like that available?

Comment: if you are using linux: `sed 's/^./\l&/'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off your sample data, you can use the following.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Search and Replace**, enable *Regular Expression*..

```
Find What: ([A-Z])(\w+)
Replace With: \L$1\E$2
```

**Note**: The following modifiers may be used to change the case of a backreference during the replacement:

```
\l     # first character to lower case
\u     # first character to upper case
\L     # start of lower case conversion
\U     # start of upper case conversion
\E     # end lower/upper case conversion
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, @hwnd